# How can I virtualize an OS for a Raspberry Pi computer on Windows host?

Tags: raspbian, emulation

I would like to try some OS for Raspberry on my computer, without formatting an SD card.

(For example: Raspbian)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't yet tried using Qemu. But it's one way for running things like this. Link: http://qemu.weilnetz.de/

I suggest you should play with Arch instead of Raspbian. It's fun & fast to use :)